# Equation of the tangent line, derivative denominator is 0

Tags: calculus

I was wondering what the equation of the tangent line is at $x=0$ for the following function:
$$\frac{(3x^2+1)^4}{(x^5-4x^2)^2}$$. The derivative works out to be:
$$-\frac{2(3x^2+1)^3(3x^5+24x^2+5x^3-8)}{x^5(x^3-4)^3}$$
which clearly has a 0 on the denominator. Looking at the graph of the original function it also looks like there is a vertical asymptote at $x=0$, so would I just say the tangent line is $x=0$?

Comment: In this case, the tangent line simply don't exist, since the function is undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tangent line to a function $f(x)$ at a particular point $x=x_0$ is a line through $\bigl(x_0,f(x_0)\bigr)$ whose slope is $f'(x_0).$ So, to have a tangent line at a point, the function *must be defined* there, and furthermore must have a (possibly infinite) derivative that is defined there. The given function is not defined at $x=0,$ so has no tangent line there.